# Gradle: War project does not include JAR built by a child project

Tags: java, jar, gradle, war

I have a root project that builds WAR, and a child project that builds JAR.
The root project references the child project in this way:

```
dependencies{
   runtime project(':childProject')
}
```

Problem: the produced WAR file does not include JAR file built by the child project.

UPDATED: Script for the root project:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

jar.enabled = false
war {
    dependencies {
        runtime project(':childProject')
    }

    // For each JAR: copy content of META-INF/resources/* to the root folder of WAR
    into("/") {
        from { collectMetainfResources(classpath)
        }
    }
}


// Collects META-INF/resources folders from JARs on classpach
def collectMetainfResources(classpath) {
    FileCollection collectedResources = files{}

    // For each JAR on classpath
    for(file in classpath) {
    }

    return collectedResources
}
```

It seems that collectMetainfResources(classpath) function modifies classpath.
If I remove `for(file in classpath)` loop, the classpath is correct and includes the JAR.
Why this loop modifies the classpath variable?

Comment: Please provide more details. Chances are that something is wrong with one of your build scripts.

Comment: I updated the question: added script for the root project.

Comment: @isobretatel Can you confirm that jar is created in "childProject"?

Comment: Yes, the JAR was created.